# How do I create name servers for my VPS package?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, vps, domain-registrar, nameserver

I have recently signed up for a knownhost VPS package. My account has been set up on their end. They want me to create `ns1.outsourcingnepal.com` and `ns2.outsourcingnepal.com` in my registrar and point to their given IP address.

I checked my registar site... I can change the DNS info and other too, but where do I create those two entries and add the IPs?

My domain name: outsourcingnepal.com
My registar: Public domain registry. (known via betterwhois.com, registered through nearby company Simrik Solutions)

I have my name servers set to:

```
ns1.simriksolutions.info  
ns2.simriksolutions.info
```

I have set my A Record to:

```
name:  outsourcingnepal.com
value: ip given by knownhost
```

I have set my NS Records:

```
Sr No   Record Id       Name                        Value                           Status       
1       10318811        outsourcingnepal.com        ns1.simriksolutions.info        Active   
2       10318812        outsourcingnepal.com        ns2.simriksolutions.info        Active   
3       10318813        outsourcingnepal.com        ns3.simriksolutions.info        Active   
4       10318814        outsourcingnepal.com        ns4.simriksolutions.info        Active   
5       10321078        outsourcingnepal.com        ns1.outsourcingnepal.com        Active   
6       10321080        outsourcingnepal.com        ns2.outsourcingnepal.com        Active
```

**Updates:**
I updated the child name server. I even added the http://outsourcingnepal.com account in WHM of knownhost too.

Now I am getting the following DNS Lookup result:

http://www.domaintools.com/research/dns/?query=outsourcingnepal.com&search=dns

```
Outsourcingnepal.com DNS Lookup
;; Answer received from 127.0.0.1 (90 bytes)
;;
;; HEADER SECTION
;; id = 5049
;; qr = 1 opcode = QUERY aa = 0 tc = 0 rd = 1
;; ra = 1 ad = 0 cd = 0 rcode = NOERROR
;; qdcount = 1 ancount = 1 nscount = 2 arcount = 0

;; QUESTION SECTION (1 record)
;; outsourcingnepal.com.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION (1 record)
outsourcingnepal.com.   13495   IN  A   204.197.252.160

;; AUTHORITY SECTION (2 records)
outsourcingnepal.com.   85495   IN  NS  ns1.outsourcingnepal.com.
outsourcingnepal.com.   85495   IN  NS  ns2.outsourcingnepal.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION (0 records)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several steps to this process:

1. **Find your server IP's**

   I'm assuming you have WHM here? Open `http://IP/whm` (or the path to your server control panel installation) then go to IP Functions >> show IP address usage & check your primary and secondary IP Address. Make a note of these two IP's
2. **Register your Nameservers**

   You need to register your nameservers with your Registrar. Login to your registrar’s control panel and register the name servers. This is often called "Child Name Servers" (See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtxcd.png) for an example) or if this option isn't available, ask them to "register the name servers" for you.

   Note: As with all DNS, this can sometimes take time to propagate.

   ie:

   - ns1.yourdomainname.tld – the Default IP of your server
   - ns2.yourdomainname.tld – Secondary IP or free IP
3. **Add nameservers to your VPS**

   Returning to your VPS Control Panel, Go to `http://IP/whm` >> Basic cPanel/WHM Setup and scroll down to Primary Nameserver ns1.outsourcingnepal.com & click on “Assign IP address” and then “Add an A entry for this name server”. Then do the same for ns2.

   Once all done you can check if your nameservers are resolving ok at http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools/lookup.ch?name=ns1.outsourcingnepal.com&type=A
4. **Add your nameservers to the domain records.**

   Now you have fully working nameservers you can start changing the domain records for the domains you own to use your nameservers.

   Some of my favourite useful sites for checking DNS are:

   [Squish.net dns checker](http://www.squish.net/dnscheck/)
   Complete DNS traversal from the root examining all possible routes that a client could travel, calculating percentage probabilities on the way.

   [Domain Tools](http://whois.domaintools.com/)
   Very useful site. Use it all the time.

Comment: i changed the name server to ns1.outsourcingnepal.com and ns2.outsourcingnepal.com ... but still didn't find any place to enter the ip for them given by knownhost

Comment: @KoolKabin I have added further details on creating the nameservers in your VPS and registering them with your registrar.

Comment: as per you suggestion,I checked my whm setting under ip functions. I found that the ips given by knownhost with specified ns1.outsourcingnepal.com and next is already there. And about the task in registar panel for registering name server i am being confused

Comment: If there isn't an option in the Registrars control panel (and a lot don't have this function) then you will need to contact them directly and ask them to register your nameservers for you.

Comment: It can sometimes be called "Manage Child Nameservers" Have a look for that in your Registrar Control Panel.

Comment: Here is an example: http://i55.tinypic.com/2lu2q2t.png

Comment: hmm... i checkedout the child nameserver and managed to get the result redirecting to my ip... see que update

Comment: Ok, it will probably take a bit of time before it starts to resolve properly.

Comment: So Am i done now?

Comment: Looks ok. http://www.squish.net/dnscheck/ shows both ns servers dishing out the results. Your domain record: http://whois.domaintools.com/outsourcingnepal.com has the ns set ok and http://outsourcingnepal.com/ is resolving.

Comment: hm.... thnx alot buddy... as soon as i become able to open my website i will mark your ans as correct one. Your answers and support is really great

Comment: No problems. It is working here (UK) I can see "Index of / cgi-bin/ in my browser and a ping shows it resolving to: 204.197.252.160 which is the same IP as ns1 (http://enc.com.au/itools/nscheck.php)

Comment: Pop a simple page up in /public_html and I can tell you what I see.

Comment: yup buddy its working gr8.. thnx once more...i have uploaded my few sample test. Will upload the site soon.

Comment: Good news. Glad it is working and that I could help. Thanks for the rep. Now you can get on with everything else that had to be put on the back-burner while you tore your hair out with this issue ;-)

Comment: nice being with you dude..

Comment: Same here, good to see someone update their question as we progress through the issue. Really helps to make SO an excellent resource for others with the same or similar issues. Don't forget to dish out that lovely +200 bounty you have there.... oh yeah baby!

Comment: If you use Godaddy, heres is the Knowledgebase article: 
http://help.godaddy.com/article/668

Answer (score 0):

First off, the wording of your question very unclear, but I'll take a stab at it anyway...

I don't believe you would need to enter any IP addresses because the DNS takes care of that automatically.

**EDIT:  When I answered this question, the OP only had the first three sentences posted.  IMHO, he should have indicated everything else as an "edit".**

Comment: Agreed, perhaps he could return and change this? My answer went through about 12 edits as the picture became clearer and my original reply wasn't far off yours. Don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

you have to log in to your registrar and set an A record to point to your VPS' ip address.
consult your registrars online help if you can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I have set the A record to point the VPS's IP address but still not working. updates in question...